# serialize java objects to objective c plist

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, google-app-engine, serialization

I have a java web server (google app engine to be precise) and which works with an iPhone app written in objective C. I'd like to transfer data from the server to the client - specifically I'd like to serialize my plain old java objects to an objective c plist string so that it can be easily parsed by the client iphone. Are there any libraries that do this so that I don't have to write this serialization by hand?

As a bonus - is there a way in objective c to read this plist string and have it parsed correctly so that it deserializes into an objective c object?

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) supports input/output in plist format.  You might take a look at the API to see if it will suit your needs.

Comment: took a look through this but don't think it supports what I'm looking for. thanks though

Comment: Please update your post to indicate that you've examined Commons Configuration, and why it won't work for you.  Somebody else may have a better solution and knowing why Commons-Config doesn't work will help narrow down the possibilities.